# Laser filters limit scan angle opposite way and hector mapping limit of scan range

Tags: ros, sicklms, laser-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

As pointed in the wiki and [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/61538/limit-scan-angle-for-lms100/) I have used the pacakge `laser_filters` with the function `LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter` to eliminate some points. However the filter acts on the opposite way I would like to.

[image: image description]

As in the photo attached it ispossible to see that the points eliminated are the one on the front and not on the back. So the screenshot have the points I would like to remove. At the beginning I thought, ok easy, just change the sign of the upper and lower bound. But, **seems that laser filter does not work if lower bound is bigger that upper bound**.

Any hints guys?

For clarity, here the actual .yaml of the image above:

```
scan_filter_chain:
    - name: range
      type: LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter
      params:
        lower_angle: -1.57
        upper_angle: 1.57
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269633/laser-filters-limit-scan-angle-opposite-way-and-hector-mapping-limit-of-scan-range/) by [matteopantano](https://answers.ros.org/users/29039/matteopantano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What happens if you chain two filters like this?

```
scan_filter_chain:
  - name: range1
    type: LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter
    params:
      lower_angle: -3.14
      upper_angle: -1.57
  - name: range2
    type: LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter
    params:
      lower_angle: 1.57
      upper_angle: 3.14
```

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matteopantano](https://answers.ros.org/users/29039/matteopantano/) on 2017-08-26**:
Awesome! It worked! And also hector mapping works! Here pic: [picture](https://ibb.co/iTyzSQ)

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-10-06**:
Would you send your codes to my mail Mr. @matteopantano? mechinengineer@gmail.com

**Comment by [matteopantano](https://answers.ros.org/users/29039/matteopantano/) on 2017-10-09**:
There is no code for using `LaserScanFilters`, maybe [wiki](https://answers.ros.org/question/61538/limit-scan-angle-for-lms100/) helps how to!

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-08-02**:
Hi, I'm using an [RPLIDAR A2](https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf2/rpk-02-datasheet.pdf) and I have the same need but the solution didn't work for me. Each filter is working alone but the two don't work together and the output is a scan with just one value because I've got  `angle_min=angle_max=1.57079660892`.
Can anyone help me with that? Thanks.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-08-02**:
I tried this configuration instead,

```
 scan_filter_chain:
- name: laser_cutoff
  type: laser_filters/LaserScanAngularBoundsFilterInPlace
  params:
    lower_angle: -1.5708
    upper_angle: 1.5708
```

It kind of worked because I'm left with the front part of the scan but the range of the output scan is like the input scan and not 180° as I need it to be.